# understanding Laravel API and API authentication (Passport)!

Tags: laravel, api, oauth-2.0

I am building a wep app (a website) project using Laravel.

I want to build a native mobile app version of it in the future. I know I need to make **RESTful APIs** routes for the mobile app to consume by users, but I also want the web app to consume the same **RESTful APIs** routes. I will be using Laravel API authentication (Passport) which will provides a full OAuth2 server.

I am struggling to understand the **OAuth2** workflow here, who is:

- Resource Owner
- Resource Server
- Client
- Authorization Server

and how can I make the the (web app) consume its own RESTful APIs?

Answer (score 0):

In order to have it clear in your mind you need to translate each one to more understandable terms:

- Resource Owner is the USER
- Resource Server & Authorisation Server is the API
- Client is the APPLICATION

The process is the following and it is really simple:

1. APPLICATION (Client) makes and Authorisation Request with a valid USER (Resource Owner)
2. API (Authorisation Server) replies with a token
3. APPLICATION (Client) tries to access API (Resource Server) passing the token for authentication

> You can check [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/an-introduction-to-oauth-2) page for more detailed information.